# unconditional convergent

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to decide whether the following statement is true or false : *every permutation of a basic sequence is equivalent to the entire sequence* ! where a sequence $(x_n)$ in a Banach space $X$ is called basic if it's a basis of $[x_1,x_2,x_3,.........]$ (it's closed span). 

I think it's false, and I think that if it's true then  $\displaystyle\sum_{1}^{\infty}x_n$ converges unconditionaly . Any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: A basis is unconditional if and only if every permutation of the basis is a basic sequence. The property that you require is stronger. A basis for which every permutation is basic and equivalent to to the original sequence is called *symmetric*. So yes, symmetric basic sequences are unconditional. These facts can be found in Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's *Classical Banach Spaces I*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate that !

Comment: Do you have an idea how to prove this statement : A basis is unconditional if and only if every permutation of the basis is a basic sequence !

Comment: It follows from the definition of "basic" (existence of unique representations in terms of the basis elements ) and the definition of "unconditional" ( every expansion $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_i$ in terms of the basis converges unconditionally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (Schauder) basis $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ of a Banach space $X$ is unconditional if and only if for every $x\in X$, its expansion $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_i$ in terms of the basis converges unconditionally. This is equivalent to saying that any permutation of the basis is a basic sequence.

There are, of course, bases that are not unconditional. For instance, it can be shown that  the sequence $\{e_1, e_1-e_2, e_1-e_3,\ldots\}$ is a basis of $\ell_1$ that is not unconditional.

The property that you require is stronger. A basis $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ for which every permutation of $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is equivalent to $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ is called *symmetric* (recall that two basic sequences $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ are *equivalent* if the convergence of $\sum\alpha_i x_i$ is equivalent to that of $\sum\alpha_i y_i$).

Of note:

- For $1<p<\infty$, the space $L_p(0,1)$ does not have a symmetric
  basis (it in fact does not possess a subsymmetric basis)$\,^1$. So the
  [Haar system](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Haar_system) in these spaces gives an example of an unconditional
  basis that is not symmetric.
- The sequence $(x_i)$ constructed in my answer to [this
  post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120180/ell-1-and-unconditional-convergence/120318#120318)
  is an unconditional basic sequence in $\ell_1$.  It follows from the
  results there that this sequence is not equivalent to the standard
  unit vector basis of $\ell_1$. So from the last point below, it
  follows that $(x_n)$ is not symmetric.
- If $X$ is one of $c_0$, $\ell_1$, or $\ell_2$, then every unconditional
  basis of $X$ is symmetric. This follows from the fact that these
  spaces have unique unconditional bases$\,^2$.
- If $X$ is one of $c_0$, $\ell_p$ $1\le p<\infty$, then every symmetric
  basis of $X$ is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $X$.
  In
  fact,  any
  symmetric basic sequence in $X$ is equivalent to the standard unit
  vector basis of $X$$\,^3$.

$^1$ c.f., Ivan Singer, *Bases in Banach Spaces*, Chapter 22.

$^2$ This is a well known fact. See, e.g., Singer or Joeseph Diestel's *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*.

$^3$ c.f. Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri *Classical Banach Spaces I*, proposition 3.b.5 and the remark following.