# Series with elements in $l^{\infty}$ that converge unconditionally but not absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $V$ be a Banach space and let $v$ and $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ belong to $V$.

> We say that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v_k$ converges
> unconditionally to $v$ if for each positive $\varepsilon$ there is a
> finite subset $F_\varepsilon$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that
> $\lVert\sum_{k\in F}v_k -v \rVert<\varepsilon$ holds whenever $F$ is a
> finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that includes $F_{\varepsilon}$.

Now, let $V=l^{\infty}=\{\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\mid \lVert\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\rVert_{\infty}<+\infty\}$. Show that there exists a sequence $v_1,v_2,\ldots$ in $V$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v_k$ converges unconditionally to some $v$, but does not converge absolutely.

Comment: Try $v_n(m)=0$ for $m\ne n$, $v_n(n)=1/n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674882/difference-between-unconditional-and-absolute-convergence-in-banach-spaces

Comment: Thanks @DavidMitra